# Fivestar widget doesn't refresh after voting

Tags: drupal, drupal-fivestar, drupal-modules

I have a question about using the Fivestar module. When I vote a node the vote is processed, but the widget showing the average doesn't reload until I reload the node.

Does anybody know what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a conflict in js scripts. Try to debug it by FireBug or Web Developer addons fo FireFox.

Enjoy ;)